# How To Validate an EditText to handle numbers only in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I validate a text view in android to handle positive integer numbers?

I don't want it to accept any character or signs etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the EditText's [`inputType` attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)? You can set a whole bunch of different input types that the EditText should limit the user input to.

From the sounds of it, you're probably looking for something like:

```
<EditText
    ....
    android:inputType="number" 
     ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions. See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Your pattern could look like `^[0-9]{1,10}$`
which means that the entered value can only consist of digits (minimum 1, maximum 10)

Answer (score 3):

IMO best way is use inputType in xml

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

You have to remember that "+" is also part of the phone number.

Comment: Not that I've checked this in android but '*' and '#' also can be used in a phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code in your `Edittext` XML to restrict any range of values

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from XML

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

or programmatically

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```